# Nested layout for android app is not working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-xml

This is my XML file that I created. I am unable to set the `LinearLayout`'s height. I have set the `LinearLayout`'s orientation to horizontal and I have used `layout_weight` to set the height of `LinearLayout`.

However when I am setting the `TextView`'s height to `match_parent` it doesn't work.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:weightSum="3">

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/a"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="2"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/b"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@id/a">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="3"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="4"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/c"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@id/b">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="5"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="6"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What do "not working" and "doesn't work" mean?

Answer (score 0):

It is not working because `RelativeLayout` (your root layout) does not support weights. So change your top level `RelativeLayout` to `LinearLayout` with `vertical orientation` and it should work.